# set up Swift-Clean to use its features

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

i get this warning on main storyboard
xcode Version 7.2 (7C68)

warning: You have to install and set up Swift-Clean to use its features!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You (or someone for you) installed Swift-Clean (www.swiftcleanapp.com) into your project and forgot to add the preferences that Swift-Clean needs in order to check your code.

If you want to use Swift-Clean, you need to go to www.swiftcleanapp.com/survey.php, take the survey and download the .plist file that you'll insert into your project. Build the project; Swift-Clean will show you warnings if your code isn't compliant with the rules you specified.

If you want to delete Swift-Clean from your project, simply go to your target preferences (Project navigator > project name > select your target) and go to "Build Phases". You'll find a "Swift-Clean Run Script" Run Script Phase. Delete it by clicking on the "x" on the right side.

Answer (score 1):

Also, to use Swift-Clean as it's automatically configured, the .app bundle needs to be in the Application folder.